# Play Demon Front in a emulator?

Tags: emulation, backwards-compatibility, arcade, demon-front

I have the PCB but my CAB is actually out of service. I saw that there is a dump of the game out there. But when I try it in MAME, there is just a kind of counter that counts to 0 and then nothing happens.

Is there a way to play it?
I found some [screenshots](http://nfggames.com/games/DemonFront/). They look like they are made in a emulator so i assume there is a possibility to play it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: could you expand your abbreviations?
Printed Circuit Board? Cabinet?

Comment: you got them all right :P I just wanted to say that i own the orgintal game but my cabinet is out of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it works in mame 0.138.  Also, try the PGM bios.  Assuming you actually have a real copy of it.

Comment: yes i have the real copy. I saw that it should work. But it just shows this countdown. I have the PGM Bios rom.

Comment: Maybe your DemonFront rom is corrupted?  Try rebuilding/reacquiring it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Nebula Emulator. Its Windows Freeware (http://emulator-zone.com/doc.php/arcade/nebula.html). Finding the ROM may take a shuffle but should get you by.

Good Luck Gaming!

Comment: it does the same in Nebula :(